# Excel VBA - Click a button when the buttons have the same name

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, dom, dojo, vba

I have a website where all of the buttons have the same class name and the only differentiating part of the button is the "data-dojo-attach-point".

I am trying to click that button or select that field and input values.

```
<div class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="searchAddress">Search</div>

<div class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="buildToAddress">Build to Address</div>
```

i.e. like this

```
    Set element = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")
element.Item(0).Click
```

Does anyone know how I can select the correct button to click?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `getAttribute("data-dojo-attach-point")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CSS selectors like in the below example with `.querySelector()`:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim objNode As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Navigate "file://C:\tmp.htm"
        .Visible = True
        Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop ' wait IE
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop ' wait document
        Set objNode = .document.querySelector("div[data-dojo-attach-point='buildToAddress']")
        Debug.Print objNode.innerText ' "Build to Address"
        objNode.Click
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

I saved `C:\tmp.htm` for testing with the following content:

```html
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <body>
        <div class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="searchAddress">Search</div>
        <div class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="buildToAddress">Build to Address</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is one more example, uses `.getElementsByClassName()` and `.getAttribute()`:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim colNodes As Object
    Dim objNode As Object
    Dim strTarget As String

    strTarget = "buildToAddress"
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Navigate "file://C:\tmp.htm"
        .Visible = True
        Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop ' wait IE
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop ' wait document
        Set colNodes = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")
        For Each objNode In colNodes
            If objNode.getAttribute("data-dojo-attach-point") = strTarget Then Exit For
        Next
        If Not objNode Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print objNode.innerText ' "Build to Address"
            objNode.Click
        End If
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see in Immediate window `objNode.innerText` is "Build to Address" that corresponds to target node having `data-dojo-attach-point="buildToAddress"`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!